# Simple js forloop only iterates onces

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a JS for loop that iterates over all elements with a specific class, and then removes the class. However, whilst the loop works for the first element found, it then stops. I cannot see any errors, I've tried it inside a try/catch, and can't see anything else that might be causing the problem. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks :)

```
let visibleTags = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
console.log(visibleTags.length) // length is 2

for (let index = 0; index < visibleTags.length; index++) {
   console.log(index); // 0
   visibleTags[index].classList.remove('show'); // removes 'show' from element 0
}

// element 1 still has the 'show' class and was not touched by the loop... ?
```

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName` returns a _live_ [HTMLCollection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). When you're removing an element from the collection with length of 2, `index < visibleTags.length` won't pass anymore, and the loop will be finished.

Comment: To elaborate a little on what Teemu said - for such use cases it's always a good idea to reverse the loop. In other words count backwards from visibleTags.length-1 to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visibleTags` is a "live" DOM query - the elements within it will change as the DOM changes.

Therefore, when you remove the `show` class from an element, it simultaneously disappears from `visibleTags`, since your query was for elements with the `show` class. Thus, as soon as you remove the class, `visibleTags.length` drops to `1`, and your loop will exit because the loop counter is already at 1.

There's a number of ways to work with this:

- One solution to this is to run the loop backwards, so that it starts at `visibleTags.length` and counts back to zero. This way, you can remove the elements and the length will drop, but you'll then move onto the previous one and the loop carries on.
- Another option is to run the loop as a `while` loop and just keep removing the first item: ie:

  ```
  while (visibleTags.length) {
      visibleTags[0].classList.remove('show');
  }
  ```

  This would be my preferred solution.
- Finally, you may opt to create a non-live array of the elements that you can loop through. You probably don't need to do this, but it may be a useful option if you need to loop through the same list of elements again later on (eg maybe to restore the `show` class).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use indexes, `visibleTag` is a live collection and you're modifying part of the selection criteria (the `show` class) so the collection itself will change. Since you want to remove `show` from everything that has the `show` class, using a `while` loop like this is better:

```js
let shown = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
while(shown.length > 0) {
  shown[0].classList.remove('show');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="show">1</div>
  <div class="show">2</div>
  <div class="show">3</div>
  <div class="show">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `document.getElementsByClassName()` is referencing the **actual** array of elements matching your class.

So when iterating and changing its class, the element itself does not belongs anymore to the array, thus the index becomes index-1.

A workaround, if you haven't another path to reach the object, is to rely on another class/selector to retrieve the list of elements:

```js
let visibleTags = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
console.log(visibleTags.length) // length is 2

for (let index = 0; index < visibleTags.length; index++) {
   console.log(index); // 0
   visibleTags[index].classList.remove('show'); // removes 'show' from element 0
}
```

```css
.test { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.show {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="show test">1</div>
  <div class="show test">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function:

```js
function removeClassFromElements(className) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(`.${className}`)
    .forEach(el => el.classList.remove(className));
}
```

For your case:

```js
removeClassFromElements('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `querySelectorAll` to select all the element with class `show`.

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors. Read more about this selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
function removeClass() {
    let visibleTags = document.querySelectorAll(".show");
    console.log("Number of selected Elements: ", visibleTags.length); // length is 2

    for (let index = 0; index < visibleTags.length; index++) {
         console.log("Index: ", index); // 0
         visibleTags[index].classList.remove("show"); // removes 'show' from element 0
    }
}
```

```css
.show {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="removeClass()">Remove Class</button>
  <br/>
   <br/>
  <div>
      <div class="show test">1</div>
      <div class="show test">2</div>
    </div>
```